# UITableViewCell Constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

So I've been trying to make a custom layout of a `UITableViewCell` that it contains an image and label, as you can see it in the picture below.

[image: Custom Layout]

The main problem is the compression and hugging I haven't put my finger on it and I can't understand why the image expands, I have changed the compression and hugging of both

IMAGE SETTINGS:

[image]

LABEL SETTINGS:

[image: Label]

Any Suggestions on how I can fix the shrinking of the label?

Comment: You needn't give both the `Top` + `Bottom` and the `Align Centre Y` constraints. They can be conflictive if the `Top` and `Bottom` constraint constants differ in value.

Comment: you cannot set the image to fixed width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content hugging is scaled so that larger numbers mean "do more hugging".  In other words, your label (Content hugging priority = 251) will try to make its size match the content size more than your image (Content hugging priority = 249).

To do what you want, you need the priorities the other way around.

That said, you'll probably find that the layout is better anyway if you set the image to be a fixed width or fixed aspect ratio, otherwise it's going to look weird when these are in a table.  If you do that, then you won't need to adjust the hugging priority because everything will be constrained.

Also, @matthews is right, you should get rid of the Center Y constraint because it's meaningless when it's together with the Top and Bottom constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can give constraints for ImageView i.e Leading,Top,Height(Itself),Width(Itself) and Trailing space to label,then for label i.e Top,Trailing and Height itself.Hope It will work as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you:

For `UIImageView`
[image]

For `UILabel`
[image]

Use below code for self sizing cell

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```